# Dependency Injection - AddDbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am very new to DI and am trying to learn my ropes.

I am trying to create a webapi on aspnet core, where I use dependency injection to create a repository to make use of data entity framework core. My goal is to try to use it with Sql server first and see how it goes so that I can expand it later to use with Oracle.

This is the structure of my test:

[image]

My intention is create a Repository called ReceiptRepository which implements IReceiptRepository and only dependent on ReceiptDbContext where it keeps the context of the database I want to access.

On StartUp.cs, I inject the DI in the service

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
(optionBuilder.Options);
            //services.AddDbContext<dbContext>();
            services.AddDbContext<ReceiptDbContext>(Options => Options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddScoped<IReceiptRepository, ReceiptRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }
```

The project compiled without error, but returned no data when I checked it with postman, although my database has data.

[image]

Further check reveals an exception in the GetAll() function in the receiptController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestReceipt.Core.Intefaces;
using TestReceipt2.Models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace TestReceipt2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReceiptController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IReceiptRepository _receiptRepository;

        public ReceiptController(IReceiptRepository receiptRepository)
        {
            _receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_receiptRepository.GetAll());
        }
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseCache(Duration =60, Location =ResponseCacheLocation.Client)]
        public IEnumerable<Receipt> GetAll()
        {
            return _receiptRepository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}",Name ="GetReceipt")]
        public IActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            var Item = _receiptRepository.Find(id);
            if (Item==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(Item);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Receipt value)
        {
            if (value==null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            TryValidateModel(value);
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _receiptRepository.Add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer", new { controller = "Receipt", id = value.ID });
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Put(string id, [FromBody]Receipt value)
        {
            var receipt = _receiptRepository.Find(id);
            _receiptRepository.Update(value);
            return new NoContentResult();
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            _receiptRepository.Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception:

[image]

I think I probably know the cause of the error. The ReceiptDBContext is probably not properly injected in Startup.cs, hence it is not available for use. However, I do not know how to correct my bug.

I have tried:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    var dbContext = new ReceiptDbContext(optionBuilder.Options);

    services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(); // Compiler error...


    Services.AddScoped<IReceiptRepository, ReceiptRepository>();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

But the compiler was not happy with "my fix". Please help!

My project.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "type": "platform"
        }
    },

  "tools": {
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the ReceiptRepository and ReceiptDbContext. Maybe you have misspelled the Class or SqlTable Name. Double check the DB table name and the realtive dbSet.

Comment: It's a SqlException. `Receipts` is not in the database. You have to map the table name explicitly.

Comment: As @Max said double check you classes and db schema, also between `<>` you can use only types, like object, int, string, MyClass ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx Your first ID registration was correct

Comment: @Rinktacular ASP.NET and the Entity Framework are parts of C#. If you would bother to look at the question, you can even see *code written in C#* in it.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thank you very much! it is indeed a SqlException! Is there a way to map directly the name of the database to the name of my model? I can not control the database all the time and if the DBA changes it, I will be domed. If there is a tool to automatically map what is in the database and create a model for me, it would be perfect. If someone has already thought of such wishful thinking and you know it exists, please advise. If not, I would need to catch the exception so that I do not need to do a wild goose chase.